# TortoiseSVN svnadmin

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

Currently im setting up TortoiseSVN and reading through docs etc.
The manual often mentions svnadmin.
I figured out, that I have to download it [seperatly](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/e2a42aa7f486f74e/8f2b05a44b676887).
But the [link](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows) seems to be old.
After some browsing I got [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100).
But I can't find a version 1.6.7, like my TortoiseSVN installation.
Also I'm a little bit lost, because of the many files.

So where can I get svnadmin from?

Update: To clarify things. I am setting this up as a single user, without a server. I was searching for svnadmin, because the TortoiseSVN documentation stated it could be dangerous to just copy the repository directory when creating a backup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TortoiseSVN now includes those in their install file (or atleast it did when I installed it 5/23/2012) During the options of what to choose to install i had to click on the command line tools. Now it is in `(tortoisesvnInstallfolder)\bin\svnadmin.exe`

just thought i'd share

Comment: That's neat. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: just checked with latest (1.7.11, Jan 2013) and indeed there is still an option, unchecked by default, to install the command line tools.

Comment: Also unchecked by default in v 1.8.11.23392 on May 22, 2015.

Answer (score 5):

If you are attempting Windows installation, try [VisualSvn server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

> VisualSVN Server is distributed as a single installation package with the latest versions of all the required components. The installation process is extremely simple and allows you to setup a full-featured and ready to use Subversion server in just a few clicks.

You can manage repositories without the need to invoke `svnadmin`:

> VisualSVN Server provides a handy management console co-called VisualSVN Server Manager. It is implemented as a standard MMC snap-in and allows you to manage your Subversion server without dealing with configuration files and command line tools.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could try [this one](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

When I installed TortoiseSVN on my old Windows setup, I was using Netbeans as an IDE. The Subversion package for Netbeans also installed all the required components to make TortoiseSVN work, so if you can't get this to work, you could try that xD

Comment: Thats what I was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

svnadmin is part of the SVN server, whereas TortoiseSVN is an SVN client.  svnadmin therefore runs on your SVN server and is used, amongst many other things, to create a repository.

If you don't have an SVN server, TortoiseSVN allows you to create a repository on your local machine to use - just right-click, do "TortoiseSVN" > "Create repository here."

If you do want the full server, you can install SVN separately on Linux/Unix, or VisualSVN on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I get my SVN command line tools for Windows from [Slik Subversion](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) - they seem to be at version 1.6.9, which should work OK with your Tortoise version. The toolset includes svnadmin.

Comment: Atli was a little bit faster. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about commercial SVN server.  You are a Windos guy, not an Unix guru? You just want to upload your project\documents to an online repository, right?    Here is the answer:

1. You don't need a SVN server or svn admin.
2. After installing TortoiseSVN, right click on the folder of your project, select
        TortoiseSVN| Import...
3. A dialog window asks for URL of repository, fill it in.
4. Wow! You are importing your project into your online repository now!
5. A thank you gratitude is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at my question again. I dont want to upload something to an online repository. Everything is on my lokal machine.

Answer (score 0):

@ collab.net there are 2 packages one for the client installation and another one for the server installation

see
http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

svnadmin is only in the subversion server package