# Migrate SVN repository from Google code to another repository server (keeping history)

Tags: svn, migration, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

I read some question/answers here about how to do it using svnadmin/dump etc.
Actually I did not understand properly what I'm supposed to do.

[How do I migrate an SVN repository to another SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939963/how-to-migrate-svn-to-another-repository)

I think I have to do some sort of
    dump from the Google code repository
    using svnadmin, but where do I get
    this svnadmin?

**I use TortoiseSVN 1.6.3 on WXP and there is no svnadmin.exe command in all my C folder**, where am I supposed to download these applications?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432469/tortoisesvn-svnadmin

Comment: @Neil: I read that question/answer too, but even the proposed links refer to pages form which is not clear what you have to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from subversion 1.7 you can use svnrdump
[here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) the link to the doc:

i used:
svnrdump dump https://mynameproject.googlecode.com/svn > source-repo.dump

and it works

Comment: It worked like a charm. To whom it may concern: `svnrdump.exe` is included in TortoiseSVN 1.9 (during installation, just check the box to install locally all svn commands). Once you get a `.dump` a file it's easy to import it into another SVN repository like Assembla by simply using their Import/Export online tool.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to make a 1:1 copy of a remote svn repository, including history and properties. You do not even need write access to the repository that is being copied.

Comment: I don't know. You can download Windows binaries of Subversion from http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows (the CollabNet mirror requires registration but works fine for me).

Comment: @eglasius: no, not yet, I wanted to move out form Google code, but I have no time to look into this now.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you do not have [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.1.2) is that it is a server-side program, not a client-side program; it is used on the same machine on which the Subversion repository is hosted. You will not be able to run svnadmin without SSH'ing into the host computer. Consequently, I don't think you can copy the project repository from Google Code, since you will not be able to run "svnadmin dump" from the Google Code server computers. The best you will be able to do, AFAIK, is to use [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) and [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re12.html), which discard history.

Comment: @Michael You can use it client-side.

Comment: @Neil, you can use it client side, but it won't help, since you need to specify the path to the repository on the local filesystem.

Comment: +1 and thanks so much for clarifying me this point in 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually download an svn repo history from Google code via svnsync. See this link from Google http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_download_my_Subversion_history?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step explanation how to do it with svnsync.

http://blog.projectnibble.org/2011/03/25/using-svnsync-to-migrate-a-remote-svn-repository/